# Compare each element of Scala list against rest of elements in the list

Tags: list, scala, foreach, scala-collections

I have a list of Custom objects which will be compared against rest of the objects in the same list.

My current approach: Currently i take one element from a the list using foreach loop,run another foreach loop to look through the list for elements that are similar to the taken object.

```
case class TestOb(name:String,pos:Vector[Int])

val lis:List[TestOb] = null

lis.foreach{i=>
    val ref = i._2
    lis.foreach{j=>
        val current = j._2
        //compare ref and current.
    }
}
```

Is there any other efficient way to do this iteration in Scala within same list without having two foreach loops?

Comment: Can you provide code which compiles, also input data example and expected result?

Comment: Comparing two list datastructures always yields the same linear runtime efficiency O(2n), regardless of programming language. Is your question about a more efficient datastructure or how to do "idiomatic" list comparison in scala?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried using the `for`-loop?

```
for( a <- lis; b <- lis) {
  // do stuff with a and b
}
```

For further convinience here an easy example to get an idea of the iteration going on behind the scenes:

```
scala> val list = 1 to 3
list: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range(1, 2, 3)
scala> for(a <- list; b <- list) println(a+" - "+b)
1 - 1
1 - 2
1 - 3
2 - 1
2 - 2
2 - 3
3 - 1
3 - 2
3 - 3
```

For what its worth, enzymes solution would be more in line with the functional style scala embraces.

Answer (score 3):

An approach to compare each element in a collection against the rest and to collect those that are *similar* (here identical by using `==` in `collect`). In order to illustrate the case consider

```
case class C(i:Int)
```

and a collection where `C(1)` has a `similar` item (equality here),

```
val xs = Array( C(1),C(2),C(3),C(1),C(4) )
```

Hence we combine each two items, compare them and collect those similar,

```
xs.combinations(2).collect { case Array(a,b) if a == b => a }.toArray
Array(C(1))
```

Note `combinations` delivers an iterator which is consumed (iterated over) by `collect`. Also, replace `==` in `collect` with a *dissimilarity* function for comparing items to decide which are similar enough.

Comment: Would you be able to explain how to compare against _all_ simultaneously elements instead of _each_?  It seems like this reduces to `list.map(i=>list.exists(_ == i)).zip(list).filter(_._1).map(_._2)` (yes thats ugly).

Comment: An approximation to 'all simultaneously', xs.combinations(2).toArray.par.collect {case Array(a,b) if a == b => a}` , namely, convert the iterator over combinations into a parallel collection over which to apply the `collect`.  This does not ensure all elements are evaluated at the same time, but several of them. For large collections (combinations) this may improve performance substantially.